# MYSQL: How do I create a trigger that calculates a field value based on value from different table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

In *table A* I have fields `CENA`(price), `cena_za_kus`(price_per_piece), `mnozstvi`(quantity).
In *table B* I have field `DPH`(vat).

I'd like to add a before update/insert trigger, which would calculate the value of `PRICE` field, something like this:

```
price = (price_per_piece * count) + (price_per_piece * count * tableB.vat)
```

Is this possible?
Thank you.

Edit: And the row in *table* A has a foreign_key `dph_id` pointing to the corresponding row in *table B*.

```
   CREATE TABLE `polozky` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `objednavka_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dph_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `polozka` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cena` float NOT NULL,
  `mnozstvi` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cena_za_kus` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IdObjednavka` (`objednavka_id`,`dph_id`),
  KEY `objednavka_id` (`objednavka_id`),
  KEY `dph_id` (`dph_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=63663 ;


ALTER TABLE `polozky`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `polozky_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`objednavka_id`) REFERENCES `objednavky` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `polozky_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`dph_id`) REFERENCES `dph` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `dph` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sekce` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nastaveni',
  `popis` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `DPH` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `poradi` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `DPH_2` (`DPH`),
  UNIQUE KEY `popis` (`popis`),
  KEY `DPH` (`DPH`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

Comment: share the table schema of tables involved; use `show create table tableName`.

Comment: You have `cena` or price defined in the table you want the trigger to run on and as not null.  If price is a derived/calculate value, then why store it.  Just calculate on an as needed basis.  If you really need it then I would suggest a view.  `CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t;`

Comment: Harrison: Is it not better to calculate the value in database with trigger instead of having to calcualate it manually every time in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `yourDB_polozky`
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON `yourDB`.`polozky`
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE vat_rate   float;

   SELECT DPH
     INTO dph_rate
     FROM `yourDB`.`dph`
    WHERE id = new.dph_id;

   SET new.cena = (1 + dph_rate) * (new.cena_za_kus * new.mnozstvi);
END
$$
```

Comment: It took me a while but eventually this worked. I needed to add 'new.' to the last line. I've also realised I'll have to write a similar but complicated trigger in case the table with vat changes.

Comment: Oops! I was in a hurry ;-)